# Creating tables using dbplyr::copy_to and RJDBC

Tags: r, jdbc, vertica, rjdbc, dbplyr

Just trying to create a table through `dbplyr` using the `copy_to` function in a vertica database.

I set up the database connection:

```
vDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="com.vertica.jdbc.Driver", 
                classPath="C:\\Users\\usrname\\Downloads\\vertica-jdbc-9.2.1-0.jar")

conn <- RJDBC::dbConnect(vDriver, "jdbc:vertica://dexprddbvi01.miscny.nyenet:5433/dexp", "usrname", "pwd")
```

Then I try to create a table like this:

`copy_to(conn, iris, in_schema("schema", "iris"))`

But receive the following error:

`Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbBegin’ for signature ‘"JDBCConnection"’`

Comment: Is the connection working correctly for other operations? Can you access existing tables in the vertica database via `dbplyr`?

Comment: @Simon.S.A. yes I'm able to pull data in.  For example I can use the ```tbl``` function.